# How to use a button and input fields which are inserted by ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following is a simplified example of what i try:
When a user enter a number higher than 0 in the first shown form-field named "wz", a new form with a button will be inserted by ajax. When entering a number higher than 0 another form with another button will be inserted.

The first ajax call works well, but i have problems with the inserted button and the new input fields. One input field is readonly and holds only the value of the actual datetime (for the sql db later..), the other is for entering Initials.

When no Initials are entered in the input field "abbau_ma" and the ABBAU button is clicked, the ajax call shows the datetime and the value of "wz" in the 2nd message area with id="ajax-abbau".  If Initials are entered additionally, the page will be reloaded and no error or data is shown !?.

Here is the simplified code:

index.php:

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <form id="my-form" action="" novalidate="" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="wz" class="form-control-label">Werkzeug-Nr.</label>
                        <input type="text" name="wz" class="form-control form-control-lg col-12" minlength="1" maxlength="5" pattern="\d*" placeholder="123-1" autofocus required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info border btn-search col-12" style="margin-top:32px"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><b></b></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
            <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-top:20px">
                <div class="card-body text-left">
                    <p class="card-text" id="input-fields">Place for the (search-)ajax-result</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
            <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-top:20px">
                <div class="card-body text-left">
                    <p class="card-text" id="ajax-abbau">Place for the 2nd ajax-result</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js part of index.php:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
            url: "wz-produktion-input-fields.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(strMessage1) {
                $("#input-fields").html(strMessage1);
                console.log(strMessage1);
                //$("#my-form")[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
function myFunctionABBAU() {
  //alert("ABBAU button clicked");
    $.ajax( {
        url: "abbau_sql.php",
        method: "post",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(strMessage1) {
            $("#ajax-abbau").html(strMessage1);
            console.log(strMessage1);
            //$("#my-form")[0].reset();
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

**wz-produktion-input-fields.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');

$wz             =   $_POST['wz'];
$datetimenow    =   date('Y-m-d H:i');


if ($wz > 0) 
{
    //$form_ist_aufgebaut = "true";
    echo nl2br("<div class='' id='aufbau_abbau_inputs'>");
        echo nl2br("<form id='my-form' action='' method='post'>");
            echo nl2br("<div class='row'>");
                echo nl2br("<div class='form-group col-6 col-lg-4'>");
                    echo nl2br("<label for='abbau_ma' class='form-control-label'>Enter Initials</label>");
                    echo nl2br("<input type='text' name='abbau_ma' class='form-control form-control-lg col-12' minlength='1' maxlength='2' placeholder='z.B. LK' required>");
                echo nl2br("</div>");
                echo nl2br("<div class='form-group col-6 col-lg-4'>");
                    echo nl2br("<input type='text' name='abbau' class='form-control form-control-lg col-12 text-danger' value='$datetimenow' readonly>");
                echo nl2br("</div>");
                echo nl2br("<button onclick='myFunctionABBAU()' id='ab-bau' class='btn btn-lg btn-success col-12'>Abbau</button>");
            echo nl2br("</div>");
        echo nl2br("</form>");
    echo nl2br("</div>");
}
else 
{
    //$form_ist_aufgebaut = "false";
    echo nl2br("<button onclick='myFunctionAUFBAU()' class='btn btn-lg btn-info col-12'>Aufbau</button>");
    
}

?>
```

**abbau_sql.php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');
    
$wz                 =   $_POST['wz'];
$abbau              =   $_POST['abbau'];
$abbau_ma           =   $_POST['abbau_ma'];

echo nl2br("$wz" . "\n");                       
echo nl2br("$abbau" . "\n");
echo nl2br("$abbau_ma" . "\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer as per comment solution:
function(e) was added to work with above code.

```
 $(document).on("submit", "#my-form", function(e){
   //Code: Action (like ajax...)
 })
```

instead of

```
$("#my-form").submit(function(e) {
```

Comment: thx, but the behavior is the same.  I guess the second ajax call in MyFunctionABBAU is the problem...

Comment: These are effectively the same thing since `.submit()` is a shortcut for `on('submit'` which is used under the hood. There is no event delegation advantage here when using same selector

Comment: Using `$(document).on("submit", "#my-form", function(){` is probably what you wanted to do to take advantage of event delegation

Comment: Well, charlietfl - you make my day!.  It works now!  Thx a lot.  I will update my question with the working code.  BTW:  i can't accept your answer, because it is a comment..?!